# Performance degradation in unity while calculating pixel difference

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

Im trying to calculate player excitement by getting video source from webcamtexture in unity.
I'm calculating pixel difference for each frame and based on that i'm calculating the score(excitement = amount change in a sequence of frames).
The problem here is it is taking huge amount of processor resources and the frame rate is getting drastically decreased as this calculation starts happening.

Below is the reference code.

```
private Color[] prevPixels;

public float getExcitement(Color[] curPixels)
{
    float excitment = 0;

    // To store pixelArray for the first time when this method is called
    if (prevPixels == null)
        prevPixels = curPixels;

    else if(prevPixels != null && curPixels != null)
    {
        excitment = PixelDiff(curPixels);
        prevPixels = curPixels;
    }

    return excitment;
}

private float PixelDiff(Color[] curPixels)
{
    float diff = 0f;
    for(int i = 0; i < curPixels.Length; i++)
    {
        float r1 = prevPixels[i].r;
        float g1 = prevPixels[i].g;
        float b1 = prevPixels[i].b;

        float r2 = curPixels[i].r;
        float g2 = curPixels[i].g;
        float b2 = curPixels[i].b;

        float r = r2 - r1;
        float g = g2 - g1;
        float b = b2 - b1;

        diff += Mathf.Sqrt(r * r + g * g + b * b);
    }

    return diff;
}
```

Please suggest a better approach to handle this issue or an alternate way to actually calculate the excitement.

Comment: Are you by any chance calculating this in `Update` method?

Comment: Multithreading, Compute shaders, ... Lots of ways to improve performance (though personally I doubt that figuring out player "excitement" based on some web cam footage really works anyway)

Comment: yes I'm calling it from update method
Tried multithreading by adding the frames to a queue and child thread calculating the excitement value and updating it; but it wasn't working either in this scenario but will give another shot

Comment: You probably don't need to call it 30 times a second. You can call it once every second or so...

Comment: Once a second will be too slow for my project even i'm calling it like once in every 3/4 frames the calculation time is too high.
I reduced the cam texture from 1920/1080 to 960/720 which improved the performance but still not good enough.
I'm getting issues with Multithreading too, when ever im calling this in another round

Comment: This is literally an entire topic to itself, but here's a few thoughts to get you started at least. (1) There's probably pixels you can skip. Since you're really only looking at a "person", other pixels are useless. You can tell which those pixels are by pooling the data from the first few frames. (2) Like others are saying, reduce your polls. Do some tests to get an idea of what "works" for you. (3) Multithreading WILL be needed almost certainly. Get some reading done, or post some code here with threading and we can help. (4) Lastly, Mathf.Sqrt is expensive. DON'T use Sqrt!

Comment: Reduce size of image from 960/720 to 96/72 - image analizing is almost always done in reduced image size.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the entire webcam texture, just store, e.g., the bottommost and topmost rows of pixels, and compute the differences on those. The results will be extremely highly correlated to doing the entire webcam texture.